# lodash where function and getting nested array elements

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following type of array of objects, which I saved as image for you all so its easier to see:

[image]

Now what I want from this massive array is all the objects who's **investments** ***status*** is ***complete***.

using the _.where, I tried to do (data being the giant array you see in the image):

```
var something =  _.where(data, function(item){ 
    return item.investments[0].statues === "complete" 
});
```

But um nothing seems to happen ... What am I doing wrong? I want objects out of the array who's investments status is complete.

**ideas?**

Comment: Unless it's a typo, you have `._where` instead of `_.where`. `status` is also misspelled. If that's really in your code that will cause the failure for sure

Comment: Fixed he spelling mistake sorry I didn't copy and paste the code like I should have >_>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd try out the filter method:

https://lodash.com/docs#filter

> Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for.

```
var results = _.filter(data, function(item){
  return item.investments.data[0].status === "complete";
});
```

And as BG101 mentioned: you didn't reference the `data` property of the investments object, so you were off a level.

Answer (score 6):

try:-

```
_.filter(data, function(item) { 
   return item.investments.data[0].status === "complete";
});
```

you have a typo in `status` and `investments` is an object with a property `data`

Comment: A down vote 6 months later. even though the _correct_ answer used it as the source. puzzling.

Comment: have another one